# How to terminate an endless loop

Tags: java

How do i terminate an endless loop? I could use pause break right? Im not too sure though, this is an example

```
while (true)
{

}
```

Or a for loop:

```
int y = 1;

for (int x=0; y<10; x++)
{

}
```

Comment: Don't use `While(true)` unless you know exactly how it works

Comment: With a `break` statement; with a `System.out.exit()`; with a different condition - something other than `true`; by throwing an exception...

Comment: First you need to answer the question: why are you looping at all?  It seems pointless to keep converting the same hex string to decimal over and over, so there's probably something missing.  I think you need to get clear on what you're trying to do with your loop, before we can tell you how to terminate it.

Comment: Please do ***not*** delete your question text or code. This is blatantly unfair to those who put the effort in towards trying to help you, and more importantly to future users of this site searching for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: I've restored your question back to its original format. Please leave it be.

Comment: Please don't add things that are not pertinent to the question within the question body.

Comment: ok, this was a big mistake.

Answer (score 3):

> How do i terminate this endless loop?

You could use the `break` statement (look it up), but my main recommendation is that first and foremost, you don't use an endless loop. Give it a condition or a boolean variable to check, something that can be changed *inside* of the loop.

Note that your current code shouldn't even have the while loop since all it will do is the same conversion over and over. The for loop that you have is more than adequate for solving your hex conversion. If on the other hand you wish to get input from the user and stop when a certain condition is met, then you'd best get input from *inside* the while loop, and use the correct condition for stopping.

Answer (score 0):

You can `break` out of loops.

As others have said it's better to use a condition you can change though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you must provide any looping structure with a way to terminate naturally. In other words, you can't just say while (true). Use a boolean variable and then when your program meets a certain condition, make the variable false so the program breaks out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You know how many characters you have; either:

- Use an index into the string's characters, or
- Keep chopping off characters until there's none left, or
- Etc.

This way your loop terminates when there are no characters left, and the loop control is localized to the controlling expression instead of being embedded in the loop body.